# Delphi Custom Component Knowing Which Referee Called A Method

Tags: delphi, properties, components

I have created a custom component which has a property that the user can assign to another custom component..

```
TComp1 = class(TComponent)
public
  property Comp2: TComp2 read GetComp2 write SetComp2;
  property Something;
end;

TComp2 = class(TComponent)
public
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
```

There could be multiple TComp1 components that assign the same TComp2. I need TComp2 to know which TComp1 called it because it needs to reference property "something" of that specific referee..

```
var
  comp1a, comp1b: TComp1;
  comp2: TComp2;

comp2 := TComp2.create;
comp1a := TComp1.create;
comp1b := TComp1.create;

comp1a.comp2 := comp2;
comp1b.comp2 := comp2;

comp1b.comp2.dosomething; <-- needs to know this was from comp1b not comp1a
```

obviously, the code above is just to illustrate my point and is not including the notification mechanisms that I have to put in place, etc.

so far, I have considered using the getter for TComp1.Comp2 to set an "activeComponent" property on the assigned TComp2 so that TComp2 can use that property to get the right component. While this should work, I believe it is unsafe and if someone tries to use comp2 directly or passes the reference to another variable entirely (*comp := comp1a.comp2; comp.dosomething;*), or tries to use it from multiple threads, there could be issues.

has anybody else encountered this issue? what is the best solution?

I hope somebody will be able to help :)

Comment: Pass the other component as a parameter

Comment: thanks David, I have thought about that too but it seems somewhat redundant to effectively reference the same component twice..  comp1a.comp2.domsomething(comp1a); is there no better way?

Comment: What happens when you make a comp2 that is not part of a comp1?

Comment: there will always be a number of different comp1s and a number of different comp2s. to illustrate, comp1 represents a graphics layer in my program and comp2 represents an object to draw on the layer. each layer could draw the same object but the drawing is performed by the drawing object which will change the z-order based on which layer it is drawn on. the drawing functions do not work if not being called from a specific layer but the information about the object is still available so someone can decide to use it or not

Comment: What happens if comp1a and comp1b refer to the same comp2?

Comment: they will do. that's why comp2 needs to know whether it was called from comp1a or comp1b. comp1a has its property set to layer 1 while comp1b's property is layer 2. comp2 will read this property to determine how to draw.

Comment: So pass a parameter then, it's very hard to see past that option

Comment: If I understand your design correctly you want your comp2 to act as data container which stores some common data and can then be reused by multiple different comp1 components which acts as interfaces for your objects and store aditional data specific to those objects like positon for instance. Is my understanding of your desired design correct?

Comment: @SilverWarior yes, that's the sort of thing

Comment: Then you are forced to two options: First is passing reference of the calling object as aditional parameter of your dosmething method as it was already suggested by others. If you decide to use this approach pay special atention to not cause circular referencing. Second approach would be moving your comp2.dosomething procedure into comp1. This way the dosomething method will be executed within the scope od comp1 component and therefore you would have direct acces to all of its fields or properties. And you could still acces data from comp2 by using the Comp2 reference field.

Comment: Now if you are interested I'm willing to discus this approach in greater detail with you since I spent quite some time studiny of such aproach and its posible usage in computer games (entity system with great data reusability, animation synchronization of multiple objects, reducing the size of the level maps by implementing data reusability, etc.). Just let me know and we can discus which means of comunication would suit you best.

Answer (score 2):

In the line:

```
comp1b.comp2.dosomething; <-- needs to know this was from comp1b not comp1a
```

The call to `doSomething` has absolutely no knowledge of `comp1b`. You should think of this as two separate lines of code:

```
LocalComp2 := comp1b.comp2;
LocalComp2.doSomething;
```

So as per David's comment, you need to pass the other component as a parameter. I.e.

```
comp1b.comp2.doSomething(comp1b);
```

This, by the way, is a stock-standard technique used throughout Delphi code. The best example is `TNotifyEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject) of object;` and is used in calls like:

```
ButtonClick(Self);
MenuItemClick(MainMenu);
```

---

You ask in a comment:

> I have thought about that too but it seems somewhat redundant to effectively reference the same component twice.. comp1a.comp2.domsomething(comp1a); is there no better way?

As I said, the bit `comp2.domsomething` has no knowledge of the `comp1a.` just before it. So as far as the compiler is concerned it's not redundant. In fact it's also possible to call `comp1a.comp2.domsomething(SomeOtherComponent)`.

#### However, that said, there is a better way.

Currently your code violates a princple called the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Users of `TComp1` are exposed to details abobut `TComp2` even if they don't care about `TComp2`. This means that you can find yourself repeatedly writing:

```
comp1a.comp2.doSomething(comp1a);
comp1b.comp2.doSomething(comp1b);
comp1a.comp2.doSomething(comp1a);
comp1c.comp2.doSomething(comp1c);
```

To avoid that, fix the Law of Demeter violation by writing:

```
procedure TComp1.doSomething;
begin
  comp2.doSomething(Self);
end;
```

Now your earlier lines become:

```
comp1a.doSomething;
comp1b.doSomething;
comp1a.doSomething;
comp1c.doSomething;
```

Comment: thanks craig. that's a good explanation but it leads to a follow on question..  if TComp2 is a base class that I have other classes deriving from with different methods, do I have to have a method in TComp1 for each one of those methods? TComp1 doesn't necessarily now what methods are in TComp2

Comment: @Dan It depends on what you want `TComp1` to be able to do. However, your question leads me to suspect you might be trying to make `TComp1` a "do everything" class. And this is totally contrary to the ideas behind OO.

Comment: conceptually, I have several objects derived from TContent classes, each containing methods to play, stop (etc) with different params but their content is layer specific. that's why the TContent derrived classes are responsible for the drawing. I have a TLayer which has a property to assign which TContent is going to be drawn on it and TLayer also has other properties and methods specific to the layer but to follow the loose coupling, the only thing the TContent needs to know is which layer it is needing to draw for.. if that makes sense

Comment: @Dan Then `TContent` should define _interface_ (meaning the methods you interact with **not** the keyword of the same name). Subclasses of of `TContent` provide implemntation specific details by **override**ing key methods in `TContent`. This way the client of your content doesn't need to change every time you add new content-types. This is an important principle of OO, but it can be tricky define the correct "abstraction" for any content to be controlled by your client.

Comment: If you get it right then client code only has reference to a `TContent` instance which _behaves_ differently depending on the actual subclass that was created.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to pass the extra information as a parameter. Like this:

```
comp1b.comp2.dosomething(comp1b);
```

Expecting `comp2` to be able to work out whether it was referenced from `comp1a` or `comp1b` is unrealistic, and frankly would be an indication of a poor design.

Parameters are explicit and so demonstrate clear intent to the reader.